# Waiting for promise before returning value

Tags: sql-server, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am creating a node server which helps me managing a database. I am creating an overview of how many elements are inside a certain queue-table in the database, for that I am using the following function:

```
var getRowCount = function(table) {
    var result = 0;
    new sql.Request()
        .query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM Queue_' + table)
        .then(function(recordset) {
            result = recordset[0].count;
        })
        .catch(err => console.dir(err));

    return result;
};
```

Note: I am using ES6 but am transpiling with Babel, that is why I am not using template literations for the SQL query.

My issue is, that this function always returns `0` when sending the information to my client (via socket.io). How do I wait for the promise of the query before returning the result?

For the SQL I am using [node-mssql](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sql query is a promise, so simply handle it correctly:

```
var getRowCount = function(table) {
    return new sql.Request().query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM Queue_' + table);
};
```

Then, from the outside, you'd use it in the following way:

```
   getRowCount(myTable).then(
     function (recordset) {
        //  send result here
     },
     function (err) {
       // send error here
     }
   );
```

This is the common practice with IO and promises/async code in general in node.js

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to get accomplished, thank you!

Comment: `sql.Request` itself returns a promise, so just return that. Using deferred in this way is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @RGraham Thanks, I didnt notice the only thing being done is returning the promise's result. I fixed my answer

Comment: @buddy123 Not quite. `return new sql.Request().query(...).then(function() { return log(table, recordset[0].count); });` It's actually returning the value from the `log` function

Comment: I can dump the log function, so that is alright, gonna remove it from the question aswell

Comment: Okay, tested it and now I am having the problem that I am sending the Promise object to the client, which is obviously still pending. What is the issue here? @RGraham

Comment: @buddy123 Do you think that the `catch` is better than the `then` callback for the error?